# Caching objects but ignoring NULL properties to save space in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, caching, serialization

I have a strongly typed list of objects I want to cache, that will have a lots of properties that are `null`.  I would like to ignore those when caching these to save space.  Is there something I can specifically do to save space on caching properties with `null` values?

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, 
   data.Data, 
   null, 
   DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(data.Minutes ?? minutes), 
   TimeSpan.Zero, 
   System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default, 
   null);
```

Comment: So after digging around through reference assemblies, unless you have a custom CacheProvider, the `HttpRuntime.Cache` is nothing more than an elaborate wrapper around a `Hashtable`. So if you're note serializing your objects and storing them as-is, null properties should not occupy any memory?

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Web/Cache/CacheInternal.cs#L602

Comment: Wonder if I should serialist it to Json and back or is that too much of a performance hit.

Comment: without further info about the use case it's hard to tell. What data is it? how much of it is there? how long is it cached for on average? how is it used when retrieved?

Comment: @MikeFlynn serializing an object model to Json will usually *increase* the space used, not reduce it - and that's just in terms of the raw storage for the cached data; you'll also need to deserialize (which is: allocate) *every time you access it*; there are exceptions, but: a specific example would *really* help here; the default answer, as zaitsman says, would be simply: leave it alone

Comment: also note: *properties* don't actually cost anything; it is *fields* that do - there may be some ways to optimize the internals of your type *without* changing how it appears to the outside world - perhaps using a value vector and a presence bitmap; again, a concrete example would *really* help

Comment: If I have a class of 75 properties, and 70 of them will be NULL, why would storing a JSON version of that with NULL properties being ignored take up more space than the normal storing of an object.  I just dont see that as the case.